# Why does "Windows fail to start" when attempting to install Windows 10 x64 on a new SSD using a bootable USB?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios, windows-installation, bootable-media

I am trying to upgrade my Samsung 840 EVO 120GB SSD with a Samsung 850 EVO 500GB SSD. I created a bootable USB of Windows 10 x64 on a 16GB NTSF bootable USB stick. When I plug my new SSD in and enter the BIOS, I see this:

[image: BIOS menu]

When I select `USB DISK 2.0 PMAP`, I get the following error:

[image: <code>Windows failed to start</code> error]

Continuing yields this screen:

[image: <code>Choose an operating system to start</code> screen]

Selecting Windows 7 returns the same error again. What am I doing wrong? How can I install Windows 10 on my new SSD? My motherboard is a Gigabyte Z87M-D3H. My BIOS settings are as follows:

[image: BIOS settings]

Comment: Why do you have **OS Type** set to `Other OS`?  Are we talking about a 64-bit or 32-bit installation of Windows 7?  Why is your stick formatted as NTSF, Windows installation media, need to be FAT32.  You should use the Media Creation Tool to properly create the stick, once created change the Boot Mode, so only UEFI is used.  Any additional information should be added to the questions in order to clarify it for everyone.

Comment: Right now it's a 64-bit installation of Windows 7. I used Rufus, which apparently formatted the stick as NTSF; I didn't know Windows bootable sticks had to be FAT32. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I suggest you use the Media Creation Tool.  You should edit your question, to include that information, commentary isn't designed to be permanent